# Unit test with page parameters

Tags: visualforce, unit-test

[image]

I get this above error while trying to pass parameters to page reference. Did I missed something??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are receiving the errors because you have not added any methods and are trying to execute to statements directly inside a class.

You need to add your executing code in a method.

```
@isTest
public class myTest{
   static testMethod void myTestMethod(){
   //PUT YOUR LOGIC HERE INSIDE THE METHOD
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks manjit.. I found out the issue forgot to comment..